# Enumerating all global objects in Noesis Javascript.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, javascript.net

I am working on a project that uses Javascript.net (formerly Noesis Javascript .net) as a scripting engine.

I want to get a list of all the objects that have been defined in the global scope. Most browsers provide a `window` object, Node has `global`, is there a way to do this in Javascript.net?

Or does it require new interop code between C# and CPP? If so, where should this be placed?

Comment: Fortunately at the moment I only need a list of objects that were created using a constructor from a C# class which I am exposing in the JS context. So at the moment I am intercepting calls to the constructor and saving the object reference to all created objects before they are returned to the JS context. This, however, is ugly. I would much rather be able to get programmatically all the globally defined objects.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to distinguish from within v8, between objects created in C# and those created natively in v8/